# Radio Buttons Styles in Chrome correctly - not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

(Both Browser's latest Versions in place - Form is output by Gravity Forms so can't do much with the html architecture)

I basically have the output in Chrome perfectly - it's a circle with a border and central white space that fills background in (to be a full colored circle) when clicked.

However, even when I"m turning off -moz-appearance in Firefox, it's not styling at all - just giving me a flat, black radio button.  Code below: ANy help would be appreciated.

```
body .gform_body .gfield ul.gfield_radio li input{
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 15px !important;
height: 15px !important;

 }
body .gform_body .gfield ul.gfield_checkbox li input{
-webkit-appearance: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 15px !important;
height: 15px !important;
}
body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields .gfield .gfield_radio input {

border-radius: 8px !important;
border: 4px solid #c4e7e3 !important;

}


 html: 
<li id="field_1_7" class="gfield    radio_1">
<label class="gfield_label">Hello!  Are you: </label>
  <div class="ginput_container">
    <ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_1_7">
     <li class="gchoice_7_0">
       <input name="input_7" type="radio" value="Ready to get started?   "checked="checked" id="choice_7_0" tabindex="3" onclick="gf_apply_rules(1,[8,6]);">
        <label for="choice_7_0">Ready to get started? </label></li>
          <li class="gchoice_7_1">
          <input name="input_7" type="radio" value="Or just saying hello!" id="choice_7_1" tabindex="4" onclick="gf_apply_rules(1,[8,6]);">
             <label for="choice_7_1">Or just saying hello!</label></li></ul></div></li>
```

Any help on route to take is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to change the look of form elements (like radio, checkbox and selects) you should change them with some JS code or plugin, because there is too much restriction with css only and you won't get the wanted results on other browsers.

Try something simples as [ezMark](http://www.itsalif.info/content/ezmark-jquery-checkbox-radiobutton-plugin) or some other plugin in order to have the wanted effect.